# Laravel 5.3 $appends not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

Below is the code for model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $appends = [
        "desc"
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['id'];

    public function getDescAttribute()
    {
        return strip_tags( $this->attributes['description'] );
    }
}
```

So now when i do

```
$product = Product::first();
```

It doesn't return desc field in the $product, though when i do $product->desc it returns the result, but i want that result to be appended in the model itself.

The following code gives me error

```
$product = Product::first()->get(['desc']);
```

It runs

```
Select desc from products...
```

But as the desc is not there i am getting error.

Is anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you add `protected $visible = ['desc'];`?

Comment: then `$product = Product::first();` shows `App\Product {#729}` with not columns in tinker

Answer (score 1):

Fields that you add to **$appends** array are only appended when object is **serialized to array/JSON**. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to define this attribute until it's really needed - that's why you're getting the value when you access **$product->desc**. It's done to save unnecessary operations - calculating the value of a custom attribute could involve some heavy operations and is delayed till it's really needed.

Comment: I think $appends doest work with Laravel 5.3 or what happens if I am returning a JSON response to a separate frontend?